# How to convert RGBA bytes to PNG image?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-imaging-library

How do I speed this up?
My [image](https://www.mediafire.com/file/ufygtotkw3syxi9/ALWAYSLOADED_384_00.PTX) is composed of binary RGBA colours.

```
from PIL import Image
redOffset = 0
blueOffset = 2

byte = open("ALWAYSLOADED_384_00.PTX", "rb").read()
width = 256
height = 256
img = Image.new('RGBA', (width, height))
index = 0
for y in range(0, height):
    for x in range(0, width):
        img.putpixel((x,y), (byte[index + redOffset],byte[index + 1],byte[index + blueOffset], byte[index + 3]))
        index += 4
    
img.save("ALWAYSLOADED_384_00.PNG")
```

[image: Output]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of creating a new image, let PIL operate directly on your buffer.

```
data = open("ALWAYSLOADED_384_00.PTX", "rb").read()
img = Image.frombuffer("RGBA", (256, 256), data, "raw", "RGBA", 0, 1)
img.save("ALWAYSLOADED_384_00.PNG")
```

Documentation: [PIL.Image.frombuffer](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/Image.html#PIL.Image.frombuffer).

Comment: And how can I swap R & B?

Comment: Try "BGRA" as a parameter to "raw" decoder, ie `Image.frombuffer("RGBA", (256, 256), data, "raw", "BGRA", 0, 1)`. I'm not sure if it works, it does work with "raw" encoder.